# sparkSQL building dataframe column by column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a requirement where I want to generate table A having fields a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 with following requirements (think of this as mapping that comes from some other team for which we need to generate code and form table A).

a1 => comes from field b1 of table B => select b1 from B

a2 => comes from field b2 of table B => select b2 from B

a3 => comes from field c1 of table C => select c1 from C

a4 => comes from field d1 of table D JOIN with table C where c.c1=D.id

a5 => comes from some function i.e. some UDF

What is the best way to achieve this in SparkSQL or Hive? If I create dataframe with one column for each of the above statements and then finally create single dataframe from these 5 dataframes, will that be good? Also, note a1 and a2 above can be created with just one query => a1, a2 = select b1, b2 from B (how to specify this OR will sparkSQL internally take care of this optimisation even if a1 and a2 are derived using two different SQL statements as stated at the top?)

Comment: You do need to join all the tables together isn't it ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Not sure if join is needed for this. In HIVE terms I think join is needed. In dataframe terms I guess I can start with single dataframe with one column and then keep on adding more columns to this dataframe (at least in R dataframes work this way - but perhaps internally it does JOIN in some optimized way as we are just adding another column vector of same length)

Comment: I was also wanted to solve one of the problem like that. But as far as I understood, spark dataframe has a function withColumn which can append a column to a dataframe , however that works only the the single dataframe column i.e. you can modify one column of a dataframe and add to the dataframe as a new column. Or you can add a constant column to the dataframe, but you can't take column of one dataframe and stick that to other.

Comment: Lets say I use JOIN, will spark sql optimise above operations, i.e. => Also, note a1 and a2 above can be created with just one query => a1, a2 = select b1, b2 from B (how to specify this OR will sparkSQL internally take care of this optimisation even if a1 and a2 are derived using two different SQL statements as stated at the top?)